# maximum value of expression $(x-1)(y-1)+(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})(1-\sqrt{1-y^2})$

Tags: inequality

> If $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then maximum value of
> $$(x-1)(y-1)+(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})(1-\sqrt{1-y^2}).$$

What I try , Here

$1-x^2\geq 0\Longrightarrow x^2\leq 1\Longrightarrow x\in[-1,-1]$ and also $y\in[-1,1]$

So i substitute $x=\sin\alpha$ and $y=\sin\beta$:

$$(\sin\alpha -1)(\sin\beta -1)+(1-\cos\alpha)(1-\cos\beta).$$

$$ \sin\alpha \sin\beta -\sin\alpha-\sin\beta+1+1-\cos\alpha-\cos\beta+\cos\alpha\cos\beta.$$

$$2+\cos(\alpha-\beta)-[\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\cos\alpha+\cos\beta]$$

I thing that we can solve it using AM GM,

but I did not know. How do I solve it, help me

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1742204p11330510

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(x-1)(y-1)+\left(1-\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\left(1-\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)=$$
$$=(x-1)(y-1)+\frac{x^2y^2}{\left(1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\left(1+\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)}\leq1-x-y+xy+x^2y^2\leq5.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=-1.$

Answer (score 4):

Let $\thinspace f(x)=1-x\thinspace$ and $\thinspace g(x)=1-\sqrt {1-x^2}\thinspace $, where $\thinspace -1≤x≤1\thinspace .$

As you know, you have :

$$
\begin{align}\max \{f(x)\mid -1≤x≤1 \}&=2 \thinspace\thinspace \text{at}\thinspace\thinspace x=-1\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}\max \{g(x)\mid -1≤x≤1\}&=1\thinspace\thinspace \text{at}\thinspace\thinspace x=±1\end{align}
$$

This implies that :

$$
\begin{align}f(x)f(y)+g(x)g(y)&≤2^2+1^2=5\end{align}
$$

The equality holds iff, when $\thinspace (x,y)=(-1,-1)\thinspace .$

Answer (score 1):

You can apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality twice like this:

\begin{align}
&\quad\ \ (1-\sin \alpha)(1 - \sin \beta)+ (1 - \cos \alpha)(1 - \cos \beta)\\
&\le \sqrt{(1 - \sin \alpha)^2+(1 - \cos \alpha)^2}\sqrt{(1 - \sin \beta)^2+(1 - \cos \beta)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{(3 - 2(\sin \alpha +\cos \alpha))(3 - 2(\sin \beta + \cos \beta))} \\
&\le 3+2\sqrt{2}
\end{align}

and this turns out to be the max value.

Comment: $3+2\sqrt{2}$ is NOT the maximum value

Comment: The issue is that by the change of variable we should have $$(1-\sin\alpha)(1-\sin\beta )+(1-\color{red}{|\cos\alpha|})(1-\color{red}{|\cos\beta|})$$

Answer (score 1):

According to your first idea we need to introduce an absolute value for the cosine terms and then, using Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, we obtain

$$(1-\sin\alpha)(1-\sin\beta )+(1-\color{red}{|\cos\alpha|})(1-\color{red}{|\cos\beta|}) \le$$

$$\le \sqrt{(3-2\sin\alpha-2|\cos\alpha|)(3-2\sin\beta-2|\cos\beta|)}\le 5$$

indeed $3-2\sin x-2|\cos x| \le 3-2\cdot (-1)-2\cdot 0=5$ with equality for $x=\frac 3 2 \pi +2k\pi$.